# Как записать с помощью pandas словарь с различной длиной значений?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.x, python-2.7

Есть словарь

```
{
u'NUMBER': [235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 255, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 404, 408, 420, 431, 432, 433, 444, 445, 504, 517, 522, 523, 524, 528, 534, 535, 536, 539, 542, 543, 546, 547, 560, 594, 603, 610, 612, 616, 618, 619, 621, 622, 624, 627, 634, 40101, 40102, 40103, 40104, 40105, 40106, 40107, 40108, 40109, 40110, 40111, 40112, 40113, 40114, 40115], 
u'COD': [235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 255, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 404, 408, 420, 431, 432, 433, 444, 445, 504, 517, 522, 523, 524, 528, 534, 535, 536, 539, 542, 543, 546, 547, 560, 594, 603, 610, 612, 616, 618, 619, 621, 622, 624, 627, 634, 40101, 40102, 40103, 40104, 40105, 40106, 40107, 40108, 40109, 40110, 40111, 40112, 40113, 40114, 40115], 
u'EDIT': [235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 255, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 404, 408, 420, 431, 432, 433, 444, 445, 504, 517, 522, 523, 524, 528, 534, 535, 536, 539, 542, 543, 546, 547, 560, 594, 603, 610, 612, 616, 618, 619, 621, 622, 624, 627, 634, 40075, 40076, 40078, 40079, 40080, 40081, 40082, 40083, 40084, 40086, 40087, 40088, 40089, 40090, 40091, 40092, 40093, 40094, 40095, 40096, 40097, 40098, 40099, 40100, 40101, 40102, 40103, 40104, 40105, 40106, 40107, 40108, 40109, 40110, 40111, 40112, 40113, 40114, 40115], 
u'DOC': [235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240, 241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 255, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264, 265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288, 404, 408, 420, 431, 432, 433, 444, 445, 504, 517, 522, 523, 524, 528, 534, 535, 536, 539, 542, 543, 546, 547, 560, 594, 603, 610, 612, 616, 618, 619, 621, 622, 624, 627, 634, 40075, 40076, 40078, 40079, 40080, 40081, 40082, 40083, 40084, 40086, 40087, 40088, 40089, 40090, 40091, 40092, 40093, 40094, 40095, 40096, 40097, 40098, 40099, 40100, 40101, 40102, 40103, 40104, 40105, 40106, 40107, 40108, 40109, 40110, 40111, 40112, 40113, 40114, 40115]
}
```

c разной длиной значений созданный с помощью цикла
При попытке записать в эксель выдаёт ошибку `ValueError: arrays must all be same length`
Как обойти эту ошибку

Comment: Зачем вы привели непонятный код в вопросе без исходных данных? приведите получившийся словарь лучше. И еще, слово "длина" пишется с одной буквой "н".

Comment: Да, покажите, что у вас в `b` перед созданием датафрейма

Comment: @CrazyElf добавил

Comment: А в итоге то что должно в экселе получиться - столбцы разной высоты?

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, насколько я понял pandas не позволяет записывать данные во вне если кол-во строк в столбцах разное

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте такой способ:

```
dct = {...}  # ваш словарь
df = pd.DataFrame(dct.values(), dct.keys()).T
```

**UPD**

данный код создает датафрейм такого вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> ориентация горизонтальная а как сделать чтобы вертикальная была?

поясните, что вы имеете ввиду, или приведите пример того, что хотите получить в итоге.

Comment: спасибо получилось только при данном способе ориентация горизонтальная а как сделать чтобы вертикальная была ?

Comment: @Grechkin26, приведите пример того, что вы хотите получить.

Comment: хотел как на скрине но уже разобрался в чем дело